# Using puppet for the configuration of a custom appliance

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am planning to use puppet for the configuration of a custom network appliance. My main problem is i am unable to install puppet on the appliance, as it is not supported. I have access to the rest api's exposed by the appliance. So can i use puppet to make the rest api calls and try to do the configurations as and when a parameter changes? Could anybody suggest me a good way to handle this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to extend the [`puppet device` application](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.6.2/man/device.html), which currently only works with Cisco devices. This involves some pretty involved native provider implementation in ruby.

As an example, here is a [module that adds support for managing F5 appliances.](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-f5)